# Managing Frontend JS for Matrix Fields

Tags: matrix, frontend

What is the best course of action to allow the creation/deletion of matrix fields in front-end. For context this in a Commerce Order Field. JS is mess right now, any underlying Craft JS libraries I can tap into?

Here is the whole mess below, having issues with users getting stuck here if they accidentally leave of the matrix fields empty.

```
{#
 # 2016 Apply-3
 # ---------------
 #}

{% extends '_layouts/_event-checkout' %}

{% block content_inside %}
<section>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="feature boxed bg-secondary">
        <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateCart">
      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="apply/review"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="paymentMethodId" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="fields[applicationProgress]" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="fields[applicationSchemaVersion]" value="{{ switchboard.applicationSchemaVersion }}">

      <div class="text-center">
            <h4 class="uppercase mt48 mt-xs-0">Great, Now we know you {{ application.shippingAddress.firstName }}!</h4>
            <p class="lead mb64 mb-xs-24">
                Now let's see what you know!
            </p>
      </div>

      {{ getCsrfInput() }}

            <hr class="mt16">
            <div class="row mt64">
                <div class="col-sm-12 input-with-label">
                    <span>Tell me something that's true, that almost nobody agrees with you on.</span>
                    <textarea name="fields[thielQuestion]"
                        placeholder="Some may recognize this famous question, we want some original answers though, really think about this one.">{{ application.thielQuestion }}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 mt48 input-with-label">
                    <span>What are YOU passionate about?</span>
                    <textarea name="fields[whatAreYouPassionateAbout]"
                        placeholder="What are YOU passionate about?">{{ application.whatAreYouPassionateAbout }}</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 mt48 input-with-label">
                    <span>What songs are included on the soundtrack to your life?</span>
                    <textarea name="fields[lifeSoundtrack]"
                        placeholder="One of the most important question on this application.">{{ application.lifeSoundtrack }}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="mt16">
      <div class="row mt16">
        <div class="skills col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-9">
          <div class="skills__list twelve columns">
            <h3 class="skills__list-title">Add some skills by clicking the options on the right!</h3>
                        {% for bloc in application.skills %}
            <div class="skills input-with-label text-left">
              {% if bloc.type == "programmingLanguage" %}
                <p>+ Programming Language</p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][type]" value="{{ bloc.type }}">
                                <span>Language Name:</span>
                <input type="text" name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][languageName]" value="{{ bloc.languageName }}" placeholder="Language Name">
                                <span>Years Of Proficiency:</span>
                <input type="text" name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][yearsOfProficiency]" value="{{ bloc.yearsOfProficiency }}" placeholder="Years Of Proficiency">
              {% elseif bloc.type == "programmingFramework"%}
                <p>+ Programming Framework</p>
                                <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][type]' value="{{ bloc.type }}">
                <span>Framework Name:</span>
                <input type="text" name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][frameworkName]" value="{{ bloc.frameworkName }}" placeholder="Framework Name">
                <span>Coolest Thing You Have Built:</span>
                <textarea name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][coolestThing]" placeholder="What is the coolest thing you have built with it?">{{ bloc.coolestThing }}</textarea>
                            {% elseif bloc.type == "knowledge"%}
                <p>+ Knowledge</p>
                                <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][type]' value="{{ bloc.type }}">
                                <span>Programmers alone can&apos;t solve these great challenges we need people like you with that special know-how, maybe it&apos;s in environmental sciences, maybe it&apos;s in Politics? Whatever you know something extra about:</span>
                <textarea name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][knowledge]" placeholder="Programmers alone can&apos;t solve these great challenges we need people like you with that special know-how, maybe it&apos;s in environmental sciences, maybe it&apos;s in Politics? Whatever you know something extra about!">{{ bloc.knowledge }}</textarea>
                            {% elseif bloc.type == "expirience"%}
                <p>+ Expirience</p>
                                <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][type]' value="{{ bloc.type }}">
                                <span>Worked at one of those cool tech companies, or maybe been involved in hackathons in past?</span>
                <textarea name="fields[skills][new{{ loop.index }}][fields][expirience]" placeholder="Worked at one of those cool tech companies, or maybe been involved in hackathons in past?">{{ bloc.knowledge }}</textarea>

                            {% endif %}
            </div>
                        <hr>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">

          <div class="skills-buttons">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm skills__button" data-type="programmingLanguage">+ Programming Language</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm skills__button" data-type="programmingFramework">+ Programming Framework</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm skills__button" data-type="knowledge">+ Knowledge</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm skills__button" data-type="experience">+ Experience</a>
            <!-- <a href="#" class="btn skills__button" data-type="proveYourAwesomness">+ Prove Your Awesomness</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn skills__button" data-type="showYourThinkingProwess">+ Show Your Thinking Prowess</a> -->
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Continue">
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% includejs %}
var $skills = $('.skills__button');

{% if cart.skills %}
    var $iter = {{ cart.skills|length }};
{% else %}
    var $iter = 0;
{% endif %}

$skills.on('click', function() {
  var $type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  var $humanType = $(this).text();
  $iter++;

  console.log('Adding Block');
  if($type == "programmingLanguage") {
    $('.skills__list').append("\
    <div class='skills'> \
      <p>"+$humanType+"</p> \
      <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][type]' value='"+$type+"'> \
      <input type='text' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][languageName]' placeholder='Language Name'> \
      <input type='text' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][yearsOfProficiency]' placeholder='Years Of Proficiency'> \
    </div>");
  }else if($type == "programmingFramework") {
    $('.skills__list').append("\
    <div class='skills'> \
      <p>"+$humanType+"</p> \
      <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][type]' value='"+$type+"'> \
      <input type='text' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][frameworkName]' placeholder='Framework Name'> \
      <textarea name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][coolestThing]' placeholder='What is the coolest thing you have built with it?'></textarea> \
    </div>");
  }else if($type == "knowledge") {
    $('.skills__list').append("\
    <div class='skills'> \
      <p>"+$humanType+"</p> \
      <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][type]' value='"+$type+"'> \
      <textarea name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][knowledge]' placeholder='Programmers alone can&apos;t solve these great challenges we need people like you with that special know-how, maybe it&apos;s in environmental sciences, maybe it&apos;s in Politics? Whatever you know something extra about!'></textarea> \
    </div>");
  }else if($type == "expirience") {
    $('.skills__list').append("\
    <div class='skills'> \
      <p>"+$humanType+"</p> \
      <input type='hidden' name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][type]' value='"+$type+"'> \
      <textarea name='fields[skills][new"+$iter+"][fields][expirience]' placeholder='Worked at one of those cool tech companies, or maybe been involved in hackathons in past?'></textarea> \
    </div>");
  }
});

{% endincludejs %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll be flat-out honest; I didn't read through your code. Secondly, I think to set expectations when you say a matrix field on the front-end you'll need to understand it isn't going to look like what you think it looks like within the CP.

With that said, on a site I am working on, I have a page where a user can update their profile on the front-end. There is a section they can add multiple contact info - which links to a matrix filed in the CP.

**twig**

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[contactInfo]">

<h3><label for="contactInfo">Contact Info</label></h3>
{% for block in currentUser.contactInfo.type('contact') %}
    <div class="matrixblock">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][type]" value="contact">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][enabled]" value="1">

        <input type="text" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][fields][firstName]" value="{{ block.firstName }}">
        <input type="text" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][fields][lastName]" value="{{ block.lastName }}">
        <input type="tel" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][fields][phoneNumber]" value="{{ block.phoneNumber }}">
        <input type="email" name="fields[contactInfo][{{ block.id }}][fields][email]" value="{{ block.email }}">
        <span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-contact"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<button type="button" id="addPerson">Add Person</button>
```

The above is what defines what I'll call a row in your matrix field. It will pull in and render any existing matrix blocks that have been created. You'll need to update the `type` to whatever you have called it in your project.

To add a new "row" I used [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/how-to-update-matrix-field-on-frontend-for-user-profile) and [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/how-to-get-matrix-editor-into-frontend) to get me in the right direction. I highly recommend reading them. I think I read them both 20+ times.

Where I know my code falls short is in the javascript. I am currently hard-coding the html. Ideally I'd like to have it clone the existing markup so I don't have to update it multiple places in the event it changes.

**jquery**

```
/**
 * Event listener to add additional primary guardian(s).
 *
 * @param {object} event | The click event.
 *
 */
var blocknum = 1;

$('#addPerson').click(function (event) {
    var markup = '<div class="matrixblock"><input type="hidden" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][type]" value="contact"><input type="hidden" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][enabled]" value="1"><input type="text" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][fields][firstName]" value=""><input type="text" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][fields][lastName]" value=""><input type="tel" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][fields][phoneNumber]" value=""><input type="email" name="fields[contactInfo][new' + blocknum + '][fields][email]" value=""><span><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-contact"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></span></div>';
    $('div.matrixblock:last').after(markup);
    blocknum++;
});
```

As you will notice, you will also need a way to delete the given row. This is my example, you will need to update the logic to match your current html structure.

**jquery**

```
/**
 * Event listener to removing additional primary guardian(s).
 *
 * @param {object} event | The click event.
 *
 */
$('body').on('click', '.remove-contact', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut('fast').remove();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Note:** Because we are dynamically creating rows, we need to register/bind the click event in this manor so that all *future* clicks will be attached to this event.

I have not styled my form at all, but in the end, this is what the above markup renders:

[image]

(first name, last name, email, phone)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was surprised there were not more posts addressing this question. Thank you so much for posting the solution. I was able to adapt it for my own uses. I am not savvy enough to clone the first div, but I still got it to work.