# How can I enter data in a matrix field with a front-end form?

Tags: frontend

I want to use a front-end form for certain users to post entries. However, the entry layout contains a Matrix field. How can make a field where people can enter content in a matrix row? Suppose I have a matrix field called `bodyNews` containing a text field called `text`. I thought I could do this:

```
<textarea id="body" name="fields[bodyNews][text]"></textarea>
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, _now_ I find the answer on SE. Can't delete my question here though.

Comment: I feel you - happens to me all the time. For my own selfishness, I posted [this answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12602/managing-frontend-js-for-matrix-fields/12611#12611) on how I got matrix fields to work. I understand you found your answer, but maybe it will help you as well.