# How to delete Matrix fields in front end

Tags: assets, matrix

I created a user profile page with Matrix field with assets, I found [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/how-to-get-matrix-editor-into-frontend/1322#1322) and [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6551/how-to-update-matrix-field-on-frontend-for-user-profile) about adding and updating Matrix field in the frontend. Does anyone know how to delete the Matrix field? Moreover, I found that if I update Matrix field through the front end, it doesn't update the S3 bucket. Files are still stored in S3. Does anyone has a solution or give me a hint on delete/modify Matrix asset field? Thanks

Comment: Found [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2013/how-do-you-delete-assets-from-a-frontend-form) about delete matrix is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do this with:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/save-user">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">
    {% include '_partial/wish-list-fields' %}

    <input type="hidden" name="fields[userWishListMatrix][{{ block.id }}][type]" value="null">

    <input type="submit" value="Remove">
</form>
```

The `wish-list-fields` partial include hidden inputs showing all the fields already there. e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fields[userWishListMatrix][{{ block.id }}][fields][itemProperties][0][col1]" value="{{ row.property }}">
```

It repeats itself which I know doesn't seem terribly efficient but i dunno :-/ It works!

Please note, I'm on [craft3](/questions/tagged/craft3) so things may be a little different (although most likely just the `save-user` / `saveUser` action).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add each matrix row data inside a  wrapper with an ID of matrix row:

```
<form id="some-custom-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ redirectInput('/where-you-need') }}
    {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}

    {% for block in currentUser.anyMatrixFieldName%}
```

here the  wrapper with a matrix row id attribute:

```
<div id="{{ block.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[anyMatrixFieldName][{{ block.id}}][type]" value="item">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[anyMatrixFieldName][{{ block.id}}][enabled]" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="fields[anyMatrixFieldName][{{ block.id }}][fields][time][time]" value="{{ block.time|date('H:i') }}">
</div>

        <a href="#" class="matrix-remove" data-matrix="{{ block.id }}">Remove</a>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

Then jQuery code which will remove matrix row and will submit the form:

```
    {% js at endBody %}
    $('.matrix-remove').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var matrixBlockId = '#' + $(this).attr('data-matrix');
      $(matrixBlockId).remove();
      $('#some-custom-form').submit();
    });
    {% endjs %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ianp's answer, I was able to get the code below working.

This code deletes a single block entry from a matrix field through a front-end form. It's important to include the `[sortOrder]` array field in the form submission. This is how Craft knows which block entry to update/delete.

[This Craft doc page](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-fields.html#saving-matrix-fields) is also very helpful when dealing with saving a front-end matrix field in general.

```
{% for block in currentUser.matrixFieldName.all() %}

 <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('users/save-user') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('userId', currentUser.id) }}
  {{ redirectInput("/account") }}
  {{ hiddenInput('fields[matrixFieldName][sortOrder][]', block.id) }}
  {{ hiddenInput('fields[matrixFieldName][block.id][type]', null) }}

  <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
 </form>

{% endfor %}
```